# Check & Connect to 3G Under Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, c#-2.0, windows-mobile-6.1

I'm developing a compact-framework application for a Windows Mobile device to work with SQLServer Server trough 3G.

The problem is that the device disconnects automatically from 3G after some idle time, and i have reconnect manually, this is not bad at all, the customer doesn't need permanent 3G connection, and it extends the battery life.

But... is there any way to check (in c#) if the 3G connection is running and if not, activate it?

My device is an Intermec CN50.

Thanks and excuse my poor English.

Comment: Your English is excellent for a non-native speaker. You can remove the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use [Connection Manager's API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416533.aspx) to do this. [Here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx#AccessingConnectionManagerfrom%20Managed%20Code) of using some API in managed code.

You can check the connection status with [`ConnMgrQueryDetailedStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416284.aspx) and act based on that information.

[OpennetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/) already did the wrapping for you, if you are willing to use a free 3rd party assembly. Check out their [Connection Manager](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/fbba3976-12e3-9644-d482-1e2bee7fb9ec.htm).